# Test simple code too?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I've tried unit testing and I'm not a big fan; it's been much more of a burden than a boon. So what tests should I have for this simple 2D point class?

```
public class Point{
    int x;
    int y;

    public Point(int px, int py) {
        x = px;
        y = py;
    }

    public double distanceTo(Point other) {
        // Pythagorean theorem
    }

    public ArrayList<Point> lineTo(Point other) {
        // Bresenham's line algorithm. The same thing I've
        // implemented a dozen times in differnt languages 
        // and can type from memory....
    }
}
```

How many tests do I need for each method? The other point could be at the same place as the first, or one of it's four quadrants, or null. So six unit tests for each method?

Is it possible to have code so simple and obvious that unit tests provide so little value that they aren't worth it?

(The responses so far say: tests should be written for any parameter that can be null, any parameter that can be the object itself (ie this.distanceTo(this)), any parameter that may possibly cause an overflow, and any parameter that may possibly cause floating point loss of precision. At least four things to write tests for.)

Comment: What on earth is the `lineTo` function doing in the `Point` class?

Comment: In this project I often need to look at all the points between two other points. I could make some RayCaster (LineSegmentCaster?) class, but this is simpler. Do you have a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's possible to make mistakes even with what you call "simple code".

You'd have to run the methods once to know that they work, right?  What's wrong with capturing that call as a unit test and running it in an automated way?

If you agree with that, it's worth discussing all the other benefits that the unit will give you:

1. documentation - "this is how you use my class properly and improperly; here's what happens in each case"
2. better design - if you find your class hard to use or understand, so will your clients.
3. running as part of an accumulated project suite.  one test might succeed, but you might break it with other changes.  running all the tests will make sure you check that.
4. A safety net for refactoring.  If you ever have to make changes to your app, the unit tests should run before and after.

As for your distance method, I don't know what you're thinking when you talk about "four quadrants" (yes, I know what those are).  That's not what is necessary for testing.

But yes, you should test to show what happens when a null Point is passed in (should you throw a NPE?  some other exception?  silently return zero?); pass in the same Point as the target to ensure that you get a small (hopefully zero) distance.  What happens if it's small due to floating point representations?  Are you prepared for that?  What if you pass in a very large Point?  Will there be overflow issues?  Your method is probably naive enough to calculate the square root of the sum of squares of components.  So when you square a very large number, and the result is an overflow, what will your method do?

My point is that it's not always as simple as you assume.

Comment: "...it's not always as simple as you assume." in this case it is. The longest distances would be MAYBE 100. And it's on a grid and only uses integers.

Comment: And this adds value how...?  I'll vote to close this now.  If you don't want to write tests, fine.  It's your funeral.  You're adding information selectively.  It's at best a poorly written question.  I think it's subjective and argumentative now, worthy of closure.

Answer (score 7):

The purpose of unit testing isn't to make sure your code works when you wrote it (because face it, if you wrote the code and the unit test, all you're going to test is the same corner cases you thought about when you were writing the code) but to make sure the next bozo to do something with your code doesn't break it.  Even if that bozo is you.

Comment: I've heard that, but really? Getting the distance between two points? Some things are just required knowledge. Maybe if it was a huge complex method that you inherited from someone else.

Comment: I'll bet you're doing the distance between two points in a naive way that is susceptible to overflow.  The things you assume are "simple" might not be as easy as you imagine.

Comment: Well, leaving aside the point that your "lineTo" and "distanceTo" have no business being in your point class (because they are properties of the plane the points are on, not of the points themselves), I'd say yes, write a test case that tests all the corner cases, like straight along each axis, zero length lines, and the like.  You never know who is going to break what.

Comment: Yes, it is susceptible to overflow; it's for smaller distances so it shouldn't be a problem, but I can fix it if it becomes an issue. So are you saying that whenever you see a method that takes int's you write overflow checking unit tests, right?

Comment: Creating a plane class for a boring euclidian grid sounds like YAGNI, but that's an interesting suggestion.

Comment: @Trystan, I test for what's appropriate.  Your method returns a double.  If you square those ints, are you sure you're in good shape?  Did you come here for something besides approval?

Comment: Now that you mention it, it should return an int since it's on a discrete grid. And I'm not looking for approval, nor am I anti-unit tests. If people really do think that the pythagorean theorem needs a dozen unit tests, I'd like to know.

Answer (score 2):

Since you put TDD tag, then that consider that you write your unit tests before you write your code. Under code I consider even the interface. Your tests should define what the class does.

Comment: But then you would only test for how you plan on using it - if you don't plan on passing nulls then you wouldn't write tests for passing nulls. When I write tests first I end up not testing a lot of things because I don't plan on code being used that way, the exact opposite of what other answers have suggested.

Comment: @Trystan Looks like other answers didn't consider TDD tag, and my answer is specific for TDD. Google for "autumn of agile" and watch those screencasts, which demonstrate how to do TDD.

Comment: @Trystan If you write unit tests first, then you would have 100% coverage and you would not write functionality you don't need. If you allow passing NULL (I guess through the pointer), then write a unit test for that. If not, then pass by reference (if you code in c++)

Answer (score 1):

> How many tests do I need for each method?

You face the same question if you are not using TDD, but instead test-last. And even if you are not doing unit testing, you face the question "how many (system) tests do I need for my software".

I once had a Manager ask me

> What is the minimum amount of testing we can do?

"None", I answered. And the pupil was enlightened.

Realistically, testing is about weighing costs and benefits. You always have limited resources for testing (even if the only resource is your patience). I therefore beleive it is better to ask what technique produces tests that are most cost effective. I have a strong preference for an [equivalence partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_partitioning) approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the distance with a few examples you can get from a geographicmap. Use at least one small distance and a big distance
(this is pseudocode)

```
// Distance between hamburg and bremen (germany) sould be between 100 and 200 km.
Point HamburgInGermany = new Point(...)
Point BremenInGermany = new Point(...)
Assert.IsBetween(HamburgInGermany.distanceTo(BremenGermany),100,200))

// Distance between hamburg and hamburg (germany) sould be between 0 and 20 km.
// using same point for both should not crash
// this may provoke division by 0
Assert.IsBetween(HamburgInGermany.distanceTo(HamburgInGermany),0,20))

// what happens if you have an illegal coordinate (ie 400 Degree-North)
```

I have no idea how to unittest lineTo(Point other)